How to sum the values of named ranges that begin with
My Excel workbook contains several cells with names that begin with the same word: "capex_".
I want to sum all those cells with a formula.
This is what I've tried (without success):
=SUM(INDIRECT("capex_*"))

EDIT:
As you may see below, I want to sum all the values on column D (except subtotals, grand total and replacement capex), since their names begin with "capex_"


The edit with the worksheet image occurred after I provided my answer, but it just opens up more questions for me. If half the work is already done for you (in the form of subtotals), why not just sum up the subtotals instead? =Sum(SubTotalRng1, SubTotalRng2)

I am uncertain of this when strictly using worksheet functions, however if you're willing to venture out to VBA then you can create a custom worksheet function.

Open the IDE by pressing AltF11
Insert > Module
Paste the following VBA code:

Option Explicit

Public Function SumNamedCells(ByVal Pattern As String) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim retVal As Double
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If n.Name Like Pattern Then retVal = retVal + n.RefersToRange.Value
    Next n
    SumNamedCells = retVal
End Function

This will loop through every named range in your workbook and sum every cell that meets your input pattern.
In your worksheet, you can then use =SumNamedCells("capex_*") to get your expected result.

Important Considerations
Since this is a VBA function that utilizes a loop to accomplish this task, it can be inefficient when compared to using built-in worksheet functions - especially if you have a large number of named ranges.
This is only amplified by the fact I used Application.Volatile in the first line of this function, which allows this function to recalculate every time a change is made in the workbook. If you want to improve performance, you can delete this line - but beware that the function will not remain updated between manual refreshes (or when opening the workbook).

Final Thoughts
While this may be a direct solution to your specific problem, you can also venture looking into using a table to store your values. Since I do not know the structure of your workbook I can't say for certain if this would work for your situation, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention it just in case.
By using a table you can have each line act as a single record. In each record (row) you can store situational data that can be used to help with calculations and would open up other options, such as using =SUMIF() or PowerQuery. Storing data in this manner (if possible) would likely net you a performance boost in worksheet calculations compared to the VBA solution provided above.

@K.Davis, thanks for helping out! It works. It also works pretty well with Office Scripts
